# htaccess and image caching

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, codeigniter-url

Need Help, I want create an image access caching, example image at url

> example.com/caching/m_images.jpg

if that image exists then show image, but if don't exist, maybe with .htaccess script, to run image function at :

> example.com/recaching/m_images.jpg

to create new image with custom size at caching folder, then access again the image url.
How to do this, or there is another better solution ??
Thanks.

ps
I already have little script htaccess to remove 'index.php?' from codeigniter url

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|js|css|caching)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

so the real url of function is:

> example.com/index.php?recaching/m_images.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^images/(.*)$ index.php/recaching/$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|js|css|caching)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

the above "should" (i've not tested it) redirect any requested files inside the images folder (assuming you have an images folder) and passes the path to the route recaching.

You can then, using `file_exists`, `readfile` and `header` write the file to the browser if it does not exist.

i.e.

```
function recaching($path)
{
    $tmpPath = FCPATH . 'images/' . $path;
    if(!file_exists($tmpPath))
    {
        // change $tmpPath to a file that exists, i.e. a 404 image
        // or if you are generating an image when one doesn't exist
        // create it here.
    }
    $info = getimagesize($tmpPath);
    if($info !== false)
    {
        header('content-type: ' . $info['mime']);
        readfile($tmpPath);
    }
    else
    {
        die('There was a problem rendering the image.');
    }
}
```